# Strange behaviour of MATLAB combnk function

Tags: matlab, combinations

I am trying to generate all combination of 2 elements in a given range of numbers. I am using 'combnk' function as follows.

> > combnk(1:4,2)

ans =

```
 3     4
 2     4
 2     3
 1     4
 1     3
 1     2
```

> > combnk(1:6,2)

ans =

```
 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 1     5
 1     6
 2     3
 2     4
 2     5
 2     6
 3     4
 3     5
 3     6
 4     5
 4     6
 5     6
```

The order of combinations returned appears to change. I need to know the order in advance for my program to work properly.

**Is there any solution to make sure I get the combinations in a consistent order?
Also, why is MATLAB showing this strange behavior?**

The only solution I can think of so far is to first check the 1st entry of the result matrix and flip it up side down using 'flipud' function.

**Update: By a little bit of experimenting I noticed the reverse order occurs only when the length of the set of numbers is less than 6. This is why combnk(1:6,2) produce the 'correct' order. Where as combnk(1:5,2) produce the results backwards. This is still big problem.**

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. You should at least report it to MathWorks to see if they would agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve the ordering issue:

```
a=combnk(1:4,2);
[~,idx]=sortrows(a);
aNew=a(idx,:);
```

I don't know why MATLAB is showing this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, a lot for the answer. Your solution is a good workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `nchoosek` instead of `combnk`.  I don't have the matlab statistics toolbox (only octave), so I don't know if `nchoosek` has any significant disadvanvatages.

Comment: Nice. This method provides consistent results.